# How should I manage the loading of modules depending on Cookie settings in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I need your help. Since I'm in Germany, I need to offer a cookie notice. For that I've used this lib here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookieconsent

Currently it's working for Google Maps on the page. So for example when the user don't allows cookies, the map don't get's displayed. I've done this with a variable that subscribes on my cookie service:

```
hasConsented = false;

constructor(
  private cookieCheckService: CookieCheckService
) {
  this.cookieServiceSubscription = this.cookieCheckService.hasConsented.subscribe(
    status => {
      this.hasConsented = status;
    }
  );
}
```

In the frontend:

```
<div *ngIf="hasConsented" class="footer-widget">.......
```

Cookie Service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CookieCheckService implements OnDestroy {
  private hasConsentedSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private cookieStatusChangeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private ccService: NgcCookieConsentService,
    private cookieService: CookieService
  ) {
    if (this.ccService.hasConsented()) {
      this.hasConsentedSource.next(true);
    }

    this.cookieStatusChangeSubscription = this.ccService.statusChange$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcStatusChangeEvent) => {
        if (event.status === this.ccService.getStatus().allow) {
          this.hasConsentedSource.next(true);
          console.log('Allow');
        } else {
          this.hasConsentedSource.next(false);
          this.cookieService.deleteAll();
          this.cookieService.set('cookieconsent_status', this.ccService.getStatus().deny, 365);
          console.log('Deny');
        }
      }
    );
  }

  public get hasConsented() {
    return this.hasConsentedSource.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cookieStatusChangeSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

But now I've a problem. I want to use Hotjar (a tracking service) and Intercom, a chat system. Both needs to be loaded in my root module (app.module.ts):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-hotjar

```
imports     : [
  NgxHotjarModule.forRoot('xxxxxx')
],
```

Or for Intercom:

```
IntercomModule.forRoot({
  appId: <your_app_id>, // from your Intercom config
  updateOnRouterChange: true // will automatically run `update` on router event changes. Default: `false`
})
```

My question is now, how should I do the cookie check here? And how can I handle it when the user first allows cookies and then denies them? Somehow I need to delete them in this case and disallow any further loading as soon as the user changes the settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the user's choice in `localStorage` and then load your module conditionally.

```
const hotJarImports = localStorage && localStorage.getItem('hasCookieConsent') 
    ? [NgxHotjarModule.forRoot('xxxxxx')]
    : [];

...

imports     : [
  hotJarImports,
  ...
],
```

If the user gives/revokes cookie consent you could reload the page with `location.reload` to make sure it happens immediately.

Not the most elegant solution, but but as far as I can see, the `ngx-hotjar` package doesn't offer any easy way for you to programatically enable/disable it.

Comment: Is it bad to use my service here instead of the localStorage?

Comment: That would be ideal, but I'm not sure how you would do this as your service will not be available in your `.module` file.

Comment: You're right - this won't work. Thanks for your help!